# fit all the code inside the linewidth, or within the margin setting in latex

Tags: minted

The following is an simple example, as you can see the code go beyond the page, how could I make it sits within the linewidth with pre-determined margin of the document? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2, a, dddfdfd, gdgd, ddfds ,dd, dfdf, enl1,genl2, a, dddfdfd, gdgd, ddfds ,dd, dfdfdfggf,  fdfd):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)

    return 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `breaklines=true` option to allow line breaks:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines=true]{python}
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2, a, dddfdfd, gdgd, ddfds ,dd, dfdf, enl1,genl2, a, dddfdfd, gdgd, ddfds ,dd, dfdfdfggf,  fdfd):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)

    return 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]